# Weka exception: Can't open file iris.arrf

Tags: weka, rweka

I am trying to run a script from command line for Weka classification task, it is working perfectly for training CSV data. But for Arrf file it is not working.

Command:

```
java -cp "C:\Program Files\Weka-3-8-5\weka.jar" weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -t iris.arrf
```

Error: **Weka exception: Can't open file iris.arrf.**

The Iris file is the sample data obtained from Weka/data folder so I don't know where is the issue.

Comment: I managed to run the above command with, java -classpath "C:\Program Files\Weka-3-8-5\weka.jar" weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -t iris.arff -T iris.arrf 

But now for testing (-T) it gives weka exception error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled the file name, using .arrf instead of .arff.

Comment: Actually, its typo here. But it is not working .arrf. It is working with .CSV format. I have no idea where is the issue

Comment: Works just fine for me on Linux: `java -cp weka.jar weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -t data/iris.arff -T data/iris.arff` (from inside the directory containing the `weka.jar` file, the iris dataset is located in the `data` directory). It would help if you'd post the full exception, not just that an exception occurred.

Comment: it works now. Actually, I updated Java and followed the command you wrote. Thanks a lot.